# How to use HABTM checkboxes for options in tree, with triple join in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, tree

I must do an interface with three models: Role, interface and permisions (and other model where the models are joined), where I want to use checkboxes in tree, like this

```
[x] Inteface_1 (id: 1)
    [ ] Read   (id: 1)
    [x] Create (id: 2)
    [x] Update (id: 3)
    [ ] Destroy (id: 4)

[ ] Inteface_2  (id: 2)
    [ ] Read  (id: 1)
    [ ] Create (id: 2)
    [ ] Update (id: 3)
    [ ] Destroy (id: 4)

[x] Inteface_3  (id: 3)
    [x] Read (id: 1)
    [ ] Create (id: 2)
    [ ] Update (id: 3)
    [ ] Destroy (id: 4)
```

I want to save in the database, in the table "Roles_Interfaces_Permissions" the information, for example: if I select like this:

```
RoleInterfaceAction id: 1, action_id: 2, rol_id: 1, interface_id: 1
RoleInterfaceAction id: 2, action_id: 3, rol_id: 1, interface_id: 1
RoleInterfaceAction id: 3, action_id: 1, rol_id: 1, interface_id: 3
```

But I have a problem, I don't know how associate the interface with the action in the form for.

Here is the models:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :role_interface_permissions
        has_many :interface, through: :role_interface_permissions
        has_many :permissions, through: :role_interface_permissions
    end


class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :role_interface_permission
    has_many :role, through: :role_interface_permissions
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :role_interface_permission
    has_many :role, through: :role_interface_permissions
end


class RoleIntefacePermission < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accesible :role_id, :interface_id, :permission_id
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :interface
    belongs_to :permission
end
```

and here is my form code

```
<% form_for rol %>
  <% Interface.all.each_with_index do |interface, i|  %>
    <div>
      <%= label_tag "", class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= check_box_tag "rol[role_interface_actions_attributes][#{i}][interface_id]", interface.id, rol.interfaces.include?(interface) %>
      <%= interface.nombre %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <% Action.all.each do |action| %>
      <div>
        <%= label_tag "", class: 'checkbox' do %>
        <%= check_box_tag "rol[role_interface_actions_attributes][#{i}][action_id]", action.id, rol.actions.include?(action) %>
        <%= action.nombre %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer the problem directly, but there are several things you can do to clean up your code:

---

**`f.fields_for`**

You're currently populating the form using several DB calls (`Action.all`, `Interface.all`), but are manually defining the nested attributes names

I'd let Rails do as much heavy lifting as possible:

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/roles_controller.rb
def new
    @role = Role.build
    @interfaces = Interface.all
    @actions = Action.all
end

def create
    @role = Role.new(role_params)
    @role.save
end

private
def role_params
    params.require(:role).permit(role_interface_permissions:[:action_id, :interface_id])
end
```

**Model**

```
#app/models/role.rb
Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_interface_permissions

    def self.build
        role = self.new

        Interface.all.count.times do |interface|
             role.role_interface_permissions.build
        end

    end
end
```

**Form**

```
<% form_for rol do |f| %>

  <% @interfaces.each do |interface|  %>
      <% f.fields_for :role_interface_permissions, interface do |q| %>
          <%= q.check_box :interface_id, interface.id, rol.interfaces.include?(interface) %>

          <% @actions.each do |action| %>
              <%= q.check_box :action_id, action.id, rol.actions.include?(action) %>
          <% end %>

      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Result**

This should pass the params correctly to Rails, allowing you to work with them directly. I suppose the major issue is creating several instances of `interface_id` for each `role`, whilst adding new `action_id`'s?